# How to setup virtual Gpio loopback

Tags: .net, ubuntu, testing, virtual, gpio

I'm currently working on a program which should use a gpio pin in .Net.
I wanted to test my program on virtual gpio pin but i don't know how to do it.

I wanted to do a loopback where a virtual gpio 1 would be connected to another virtual gpio 2.

I've already done something similar with serial port and tty0tty.

Also, i'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thx, i don't have access to hardware all the time that's why i wanted to reproduce it with a software.
I saw gpio-mockup already but i have no idea how to use it to do what i want

Comment: Yes that would help me (and others). Especially as i'm more a software developer than a sysadmin so i'm not very sure on how to do what you described ^^'.
Also, what i originally imagined is that i have two software communicating on two different virtual pins which would be "connected" together (like in tty0tty where two serial ports are connected).
If i understood correctly, my second soft (the hardware simulator) would replace sysfs in your description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no real hardware available to you, there is no such possibility without hacking a real kernel driver. Luckily in the Linux kernel we have [`gpio-mockup`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/gpio/gpio-mockup.html) (and new coming `gpio-sim`) which is used for testing GPIO library and APIs.

The main idea is that. You create a virtual GPIO chip:

```sh
% modprobe gpio-mockup gpio_mockup_ranges=-1,3 gpio_mockup_named_lines

% gpiodetect
...
gpiochip2 [gpio-mockup-A] (3 lines)

% gpioinfo 2
gpiochip2 - 3 lines:
        line   0: "gpio-mockup-A-0" unused input active-high 
        line   1: "gpio-mockup-A-1" unused input active-high 
        line   2: "gpio-mockup-A-2" unused input active-high
```

Through DebugFS you may see the lines as being on the hardware side, i.e. whatever you write there, the Linux stack will consider as a state of hardware:

```sh
% mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug

% ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/gpio-mockup/gpiochip2/
total 0
--w-------    1 root     root             0 Jan 29 01:10 0
--w-------    1 root     root             0 Jan 29 01:10 1
--w-------    1 root     root             0 Jan 29 01:10 2
```

(Note write-only attribute there)

### Now demo part

Check first the current state of a pin (let's choose pin 2 of that virtual GPIO controller):

```sh
% gpioget 2 2
0
```

Let's assume the hardware state of the pin has been changed from 0 to 1:

```sh
% echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/gpio-mockup/gpiochip2/2
```

Check the state of the pin again:

```sh
% gpioget 2 2
1
```

For the output part it's a bit complicated, i.e. either you need deprecated sysfs interface to the GPIO chip or you have to run a thread or fork a process from your code to keep the context state correct. With `gpioget` and `gpioset` it's currently impossible because the driver restores the state immediately after device node (of the GPIO controller) is closed.

Overall I think you got the idea and maybe you even don't need an output GPIO line.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts ^^
Maybe it's just me but i couldn't find a comprehensive doc for gpio-mockup (which i found though my searches).
I hope this will also help anyone who would want to test soft without hardware.