# Simulate gpios for libgpiod

Tags: c, linux, gpio, libgpiod

I have an existing C++ code that reads periodically from `/sys/class/gpio`. Since this is depreciated, I want to change it and use `libgpiod`.

I have got component tests that run independently from the actual hardware. It runs on my dev machine that does not have those `gpios`. My code reads an environment variable with a different path, then uses the files there instead of `/sys/class/gpio`. I created simple text files there. I can now change these files to manipulate what my code reads and test its behaviour.

Is there a similar possibility for `libgpiod`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup virtual Gpio loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424148/how-to-setup-virtual-gpio-loopback)

Answer (score 2):

There's a [GPIO testing driver called gpio-mockup](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/gpio/gpio-mockup.html) you can load. It creates mock GPIO devices.
You need to enable it in your kernel or load it as a module.

Comment: This looks good. Will accept this as an answer once I tested it next year.

Comment: Mockup is obsoleted, one should use `GPIO-sim` module starting from v5.17-rc1.