# GPIO Emulator in Ubuntu for gpioset command

Tags: linux, gpio, nanopi

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 desktop operating system. I run the following code:

```
gpioset gpio3 8=0
```

This is a GPIO set command which I run it successfully in [NanoPI](http://nanopi.io/nanopi-m3.html). How can I run this code in my Ubuntu desktop OS, without getting the below warning:

```
gpioset: error setting the GPIO line values: No such file or directory
```

In other word, I think I should use a GPIO emulator in Linux. I search and find some emulator such as [GPIO Emulator](https://www.onworks.net/software/app-pi-gpio-emulator), but it does not work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup virtual Gpio loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424148/how-to-setup-virtual-gpio-loopback)